# Rotate angled plane in animation keep original angle (script)

Tags: python, animation, scripting

I have a propeller as a 2d plane that is angled forward, I need to automatically animate an animation onto these propellers.

[image]

Thing is that at 180 degrees the whole plane get's rotated and makes the animation wobbly.

[image]

```
animatedPropellor.rotation_euler = startRotation
animatedPropellor.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_euler", frame=0)

animatedPropellor.rotation_euler = (endRotationX, endRotationY, endRotationZ)
animatedPropellor.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_euler", frame=animationFrameEnd)
```

Is there any way to set the pivot of this object in script in such a way that I can rotate it while keeping it at this angle?

Comment: What if you give it the desired angle rotating it in object mode, so it mantains its own coordinate system and then you rotate with Python on his own euler Z axis?

Comment: Thing is I am not really supposed to do anything to it by hand

Comment: Oh... I understand. Can you provide the Python script you used to create the propeller?

Comment: It is not created by a script, it is a collada import

Comment: Oh! Ok! In this case you should try (with Python) to calculate the rotation of the plane's big face (using trigonometry) add an Empty object rotated exactly at the plane's angle, parent the plane to the Empty and rotate the Empty instead of the plane. Sorry. in this moment I have no time to write that script, but I'm quite sure it can be done entirely in a python script.

Comment: Mh I think I have a solution with parenting it to an empty object and then angling that to the angle of the normal but I for some reason I can't set my newly created object location, it's as if it is just ignoring the obj.location = newLocation line

Comment: Do you maybe have time to show me a basic example of what you mean? I am not sure right now if only the angle of the normal will work for any situation.

Comment: If you provide the file I'll be able to write a complete answer with the code you need.

Comment: Alright I replaced the heli's mesh with a cube and removed textures and just left the rotors in place how they are supposed to be.
https://we.tl/t-sIQzg7hPVe